# how to access My/Shared Queries under Project -> Workitems in VS TeamExplorer of TFS using C# code?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

How do we access MyShared or Shared Queries under Project -> Workitems in Visual studio  TeamExplorer for TFS using C# code?

And also how do we access MyFavorites items which  i see in TeamSystem Web Access using C# ?

Answer (score 1):

The key is knowing that QueryHierarchy contains the My Queries and Shared Queries folder.

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection coll = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("TfsCollectionUrl"));  
WorkItemStore store = new WorkItemStore(coll);  
myproject = store.Projects["projectName"];  
var MyQueries, SharedQueries;

foreach (QueryFolder folder in myproject.QueryHierarchy)  
{  
   if (folder.IsPersonal == true)  
      **MyQueries** = folder;
   else
      **SharedQuereis** = folder;
 }
```

See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/team_foundation/archive/2010/06/16/work-item-tracking-queries-object-model-in-2010.aspx) for good examples.

I am not aware of a way to get to My Favorites as used by Team System Web Access using C# in Visual Studio 2010.